# Wordpress different logout

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to make a custom logout.

I want when I logout to go on homepage:

```
add_action('wp_logout','go_home');
function go_home(){
  wp_redirect( home_url() );
  exit();
}
```

And I want to make a funtion that will redirect me after logout on a cutom page:

```
function check_if_approved() {
  if($v == 'a'){
     // do something
  }else{
     wp_logout();
     wp_redirect( get_permalink( 95 )."?message=1");
     exit;
  }
}
```

If I try like this it will redirect me on homepage but it won't work on function.
If I delete exit(); from go_home() ... redirect from check_if_approved() works but logout from dashboard doesn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
  wp_logout();
  wp_safe_redirect( site_url('?message=1'));
```

You don't need to do add_action.